# Accessing a previous page url into Nest js server

Tags: angular, nestjs

We are using Angular 8 for UI and Nest Js server in our application. And our page is navigating from different application page and that page url having the port number. I am able to access that page url using document.referrer in Client side implementation but unable access at Nest server side implementation. we are having endpoints that depends on the port number. Is there anyway I can access that url at Server side implementation

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a server should be (mostly) stateless, and not worry about which URL was requested before this one, especially as multiple requests could come in, the server keeping track of each previously requested URL could just take up resources. This is something that should (and seems like it already is) be done on the Client side, as that is scoped to each user correctly.